# Rendering an action outside the current view folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view, directory

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and jQuery 1.6.2. I would like to "render an action file" from a folder not in the current view file used\displayed.

In my `articles_controller` file I have:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    # ...
  }
  format.js {
    render :action => 'shared/article.js.erb' # Note the 'shared' folder
  }
end
```

Making an ***AJAX*** HTTP request from the article view (the view is the `show.html.erb` file and it is located in `views/articles` folder) I get the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template articles/article with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}...
```

**How can I solve that?**

The log file is the following:

```
Started GET "/articles/2/article" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-24 13:05:16 +0200
  Processing by ArticlesController#article as JS

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template articles/article with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Rails 3, this should work:

```
render 'shared/article'
```

If it does not, you can be explicit:

```
render :template => 'shared/article'
```

More about this on the rendering chapter at [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

Comment: Using yuor code in the 'format.js {...}' I get the same error as wrote in the question related to the 'Missing template articles/artilcle'.

Comment: Remove the respond_to and keep the render only, looks like your ajax request is not setting the right accept header.Adding your request log to your question would be helpful.

Comment: I need to handle both HTML and JS requests.

Comment: I really mean the **full** request log from your console, not only the error.

Comment: Look at the message **"articles/artilcle"**, there's an extra L on "artiLcle".

Comment: @Backo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1775/discussion-between-mauricio-linhares-and-backo)

Comment: that seams that the format.js path is referring to the 'article' folder and not to the 'shared' folder.